# SQL do not accept AbsolutePath Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I get a text file via:

```
JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Текстовый файл", "txt");
dialog.removeChoosableFileFilter(dialog.getFileFilter());
dialog.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
dialog.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
dialog.setDialogTitle("Выберите текстовый файл");
dialog.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
int ret = dialog.showDialog(null, "Открыть");
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = dialog.getSelectedFile();
    pach = file.getAbsolutePath();
} else return;
System.out.println(pach);
```

Last command shows:

```
D:\data\streets.txt
```

Now I make a request:

```
try {
   querySQL = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + pach + "' INTO TABLE " + DB_NAME + "." + TABLE_NAME + ";";
   stSQL.execute(querySQL);
} catch (SQLException e) {
   ErrorMsg(e, querySQL);
   isError = true;
   break;
}
```

And I do my ErrorMsg issues:

```
Unable to process the query:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\data\streets.txt' INTO TABLE base2.streets;
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file 'D:datastreets.txt'for 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' command.Due to underlying IOException:
```

Where it removes the skew, and why all this is happening? In fact, if such a request is inserted into Workbench, the query is executed without error. Please tell me the solution of this problem, it is very necessary. Thank you in advance.

P.S. The text is translated into English by Google Translate

Comment: Try escaping backslashes or replace them with double backslashes. Btw, please _be very careful_ when concatenating parameters to a query. This could be a very severe security risk. Better use a `PreparedStatement` instead (along with its methods to set parameter values of course).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to escape the backslashes contained in your path. For you database a backslash ( \ ) can change the value in a way that the string cannot be saved in the database. This can be a problem with other special characters like ' also. Concatenating a string containing ' to you query, adds an additional ' which will break the query.

You can use StringEscapeUtils for doing this. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html